# Access External Shared Memory in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, storage, android-external-storage

I want `ExternalMemory/Android/data/my_package_name/files/` in Android. So how I can get it.

Here external memory refers to secondary removable storage(a.k.a SD Card).

`Internal Memory/Android/data/my_package_name/files/` - `getExternalFilesDir(null);`

`ExternalMemory/Android/data/my_package_name/files/` - ?

Is this possible to get that path?

Comment: `Here external memory refers to secondary removable storage(a.k.a SD Card).` If so then post full path.

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/` it is for internal, Right? I want equivalent for this but to store my files in the Memory card. Currently, I'm looking for that full path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File dirs [] = getExternalFilesDirs(null);

if ( dirs.length < 2 )
    return;

File removable = dirs[1];

Log.d(TAG, "removable: " + removable.getAbsolutePath();
```